# MySQL Query how to show opposite results

Tags: mysql

im using this SQL Query in my PHP code:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   maintenance
WHERE
   from_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
   AND to_date >= DATE(NOW())
ORDER BY 
   from_date ASC
```

its showing rows 5 days before the `from_date` field. so basically rows where the maintenance is still pending as the date hasn't passed yet.

i want to be able show the oposite results. so all the rows where the maintenance is completed if possible?

Comment: Can't you just add `AND to_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` to the WHERE clause to stop unfinished jobs showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude these results:

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   maintenance
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT
                   id
                 FROM
                   maintenance
                 WHERE
                   from_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
                   AND to_date >= DATE(NOW())
                 )
ORDER BY 
   from_date ASC
```

Or simply, negate the condition in your original query.